# How can I fill the curves with a solid white or transparent color in gnuplot?

Tags: graph, 3d, gnuplot, fence-plots

Just wondering if I can fill the area under the curve with a color/option that does not distort the graph features, I have tried with no fill  [no filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isZpw.png) and used solid/impulses style [filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkv4b.png). Any suggestion is welcome!

Just used: splot w lines lc rgb "dark-violet"

Comment: Use `set hidden3d`

Comment: Welcome. It is important to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a question. Cheers.

Comment: I have used 'set hidden3d' but there is no difference.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some sample data. Maybe you are looking for something like [this](http://www.gnuplotting.org/tag/filledcurves/)?

Comment: @user8153 thank you. Well, the waterfall plot looks great, never tried before maybe I do it. About my data, it is just the evolution of the intensity of q in time [q (x), time (y), and intensity (z)]. I have used file by file and a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ugly hack, but it kind of works: plot each trace twice, once as a curve and once as a solid white "wall" that will cover whatever lies behind it. The latter requires a slight abuse of the `filledcurves` plot style in 3-d plots. You have to manually take care of the depth ordering, so you have to plot back-to-front.

Example:

```
f(x,t)=exp(-(x-t)**2)   # some function in lieu of data

set xr [-10:20]
set yr [-0.5:10.5]
set zr [0:1]

set xlabel "x"  
set ylabel "t"
set xyplane at 0

set samples 1000
unset key

set multiplot
do for [t=10:0:-1] {
   splot  '+' using 1:(t):(f($1,t)) w filledcurves lc rgb "white" lw 1
   if (t == 10) {    # after first splot, do not plot borders and tics again
      unset border
      unset xtics
      unset ytics
      unset ztics
      unset xlabel
      unset ylabel
      unset zlabel
   }
   splot  '+' using 1:(t):(f($1,t)) w l ls 1
}
unset multiplot
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Hi @user8153 thanks, I have no idea how to insert the files in the lines you posted, for example if I use this: splot for [n=0:52] "".n using 1:(n*10):2 w lines lc rgb "blue", instead the function how can I replace it with the files?

Comment: Also, waterfall graph looks good but I can not manage to do it with the data I have. How can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use polygons to make the curves.
Here is an example using polygons:

```
set terminal wxt size 600,400

#set title "Graph Title"
#set xlabel "X"
#set ylabel "Y"
#set ylabel "Z"

# sets background color
set object 1 rectangle from screen -0.1,-0.1 to screen 1.1,1.1 fillcolor rgb "#ffffff" behind

# allows rendering of polygons with hidden line removal
set hidden3d back offset 0 trianglepattern 2 undefined 1 altdiagonal bentover

# displays borders 0x7F = 0b1111111
set border 0x7F linecolor rgb "#555555"

# displays the x, y and z axis
#set xzeroaxis linewidth 0.5 linetype 1
#set yzeroaxis linewidth 0.5 linetype 2
#set zzeroaxis linewidth 0.5 linetype 3

# displays the x, y and z grid
set grid xtics linecolor rgb "#888888" linewidth 0.2 linetype 9
set grid ytics linecolor rgb "#888888" linewidth 0.2 linetype 9
set grid ztics linecolor rgb "#888888" linewidth 0.2 linetype 9

# moves the x, y grid to 0
set xyplane at 0

# makes the x, y, and z axis proportional
#set view equal xyz

# moves the key out of the graph
set key outside vertical bottom right

splot "Data.dat" title "Data" with lines linewidth 1.0 linecolor rgb "#8888FF"
```

Data.dat:

```
0.000000 0.000000 4.562285
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000

1.000000 0.000000 2.139039
1.000000 0.000000 0.000000

2.000000 0.000000 3.120719
2.000000 0.000000 0.000000


0.000000 1.000000 2.562285
0.000000 1.000000 0.000000

1.000000 1.000000 4.139039
1.000000 1.000000 0.000000

2.000000 1.000000 3.120719
2.000000 1.000000 0.000000


0.000000 2.000000 2.562285
0.000000 2.000000 0.000000

1.000000 2.000000 1.139039
1.000000 2.000000 0.000000

2.000000 2.000000 3.120719
2.000000 2.000000 0.000000
```

Generated by blender and a python script:
https://github.com/lowlevel86/blender-to-gnuplot

You could also use command line tools if you want to read vertex data instead of polygon data. You could replace "Data.dat" in the gnuplot file with:

```
"<grep -E '[0-9]' Data.dat | awk '{print $1 \" \"$2\" \"$3; print $1\" \"$2\" 0.0\\n\"}'"
```

or maybe

```
"<grep -E '[0-9]|^$' Data.dat | awk '{print (!NF)?\"\":$1 \" \"$2\" \"$3\"\\n\"$1\" \"$2\" 0.0\\n\"}'"
```

Comment: Hi @user2376639 thanks so much for your comment, I tried but a little hard for me. Regards.